# Speak failed: TTS engine connection not fully set up

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-text-to-speech, android-speech-api

I am developing a research app in which the phone reads the users questions from a form using voice (I'm using TextToSpeech to read the questions) and the user has to fill the form by talking for which I am using the SpeechRecognizer class.

I am using UtteranceProgressListener to detect when the phone has stopped talking so that I can start SpeechRecognizer. But everytime, the phone is skipping the first question in the app and is only asking the last question. I fail to understand why this is happening. I'll be grateful of any help or insight into this.

On top of that, I am getting this in my Log, which I'm not even sure is related to the problem.

> W/TextToSpeech: setLanguage failed: TTS engine connection not fully set up
>
> speak failed: TTS engine connection not fully set up

And this is the code:
I have written two UtteranceProgressListeners, one for each question.

```
public class PastDisastersActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, RecognitionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_past_disasters);

    params = new HashMap<>();
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.speechProgressBar);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "isRecognitionAvailable: " + SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this));
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
            "en");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

    handler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
    
    introduction();
    getVoiceInputForDisaster();
    getVoiceInputForTime();
    getVoiceInputForSeverity();
    for (String name: this.params.keySet()){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,name);
    }

}

private void introduction() {
    final String toSpeak ="There are three questions in the new page. The questions are on "+           textView10.getText      () + "," + textView11.getText() + "," + textView12.getText();
    textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

                textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(mProgressListenerIntroduction);

                params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, String.valueOf(41));

                textToSpeech.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);

            }
        }
    });
}

private void getVoiceInputForDisaster() {
    final String toSpeak = "Which disaster do you want to update information about? There are four choices. They        are "+disastersArray[0]+", "+disastersArray[1]+", "+disastersArray[2]+" or "+disastersArray[3];
    textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

                textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(mProgressListenerDisaster);

                params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, String.valueOf(20));

                textToSpeech.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[]       grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_RECORD_PERMISSION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PastDisastersActivity.this, "Permission Denied by Android!", Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (speech != null) {
        speech.destroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
    }
}


@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setMax(10);
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
}

@Override
public void onError(int errorCode) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    Toast.makeText(PastDisastersActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
    ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    text = "";
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";

    //Processing

}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}

private abstract class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {

}

private UtteranceProgressListener mProgressListenerIntroduction = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        //Toast.makeText(PastDisastersActivity.this,"In OnStart",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handler.post(new CustomRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                speech.stopListening();
            }
        });
    } // Do nothing

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
    } // Do nothing.

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                handler.post(new CustomRunnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TTS Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions
                                (PastDisastersActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                                        REQUEST_RECORD_PERMISSION);


                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
};

private UtteranceProgressListener mProgressListenerDisaster = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        //Toast.makeText(PastDisastersActivity.this,"In OnStart",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handler.post(new CustomRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                speech.stopListening();
            }
        });

    } // Do nothing

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
    } // Do nothing.

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                handler.post(new CustomRunnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TTS Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions
                                (PastDisastersActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                                        REQUEST_RECORD_PERMISSION);

                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: is `disastersArray[]` null ?? , check it off

Comment: No, it's full. I have just omitted the initialization here.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling TTS in this way :

```
introduction();
getVoiceInputForDisaster();
getVoiceInputForTime();
getVoiceInputForSeverity();
```

> But every time, the phone is skipping the first question in the app and is only asking the last question.

And, each of the methods contains *TTS Variable initialization code* (`ttsVar = new TextToSpeech(...);`) **and** `ttsvar.speak(...)`.

You don't wait for one method call to finish and start another one, even you change the `TextToSpeech` object instance and the text too.

That's why the previous calls are finished before they start! And you're getting the last one working.

---

You've to manage it getting done one-by-one yourself. Hope this will help.